# Socket io does not alert on server side emit

Tags: javascript, socket.io, stomp

I have a simple express js comprising of two routes. One to get a html page and one to send a web socket message

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mysql = require('mysql');

var app = express();


var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '123456'
});


router.get('/', function(req, res){
res.sendFile('/express/one/index.html');
});


router.get('/get_me', function(req, res){
   res.send('GET route on things.');

   io.on('connection', function (socket) {
     socket.emit('trial',Math.random());
  });


var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '123456'
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
    return;
  }
  console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
});

});

router.post('/post_me/:one/:two', function(req, res){
   res.send('POST route on things.' + req.params.one + req.params.two +'.');
});



router.get('/hello/:name', function(req, res) {
    res.send('hello ' + req.params.name + '!');
});

router.get('/hello/:first/:second/:third', function(req, res) {
    res.send('hello ' + req.params.first + req.params.second + req.params.third + '!');
});

app.use('/', router);
var server = app.listen(3000);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

On the client side i have this

```
   var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
     socket.on('trial', function (data) {
    alert(data);
  });
```

I am expecting to get a random number on the client side without refreshing when i execute `get_me`

This is not the case. I only get the random number when i execute `get_me` and refresh the `index.html` page.

Is this how socket io is supposed to work(to refresh the html page after a set interval to get the messages)?.

I am from a stomp protocol background and this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you initialize your socket only *after* the `'/get_me'` route has been reached.

Solution : Just put your `io.on('connection' .... )` outside of the route, just at the root of your application, so the socket is initialized on launch, not after the route is reached.

Comment: Its important that i emit inside the route and putting `io.on('connection' .... )` outside the route doesn't seem to work for

Comment: You have to initialize the socket connection at the root of your application. Then, nothing prevents you from doing `socket.emit()` from inside a route. Currently, with your code as it is, you reach the route, and only then, you add a listener for socket connection. This is why it emits only after you refresh the page, because you need to reach the route a _second time_. Initialization and emission are two different things. Init must be done ASAP, whereas emission can be done at any given time.